# Magento Something Like Marketplace Extensions

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Hi Guys,

I have been trying to find but all I can find was Marketplace. I needed something like Marketplace but without letting public Users to set the pricing.

1. Users create their profile which in this case is registered members
2. Admin will create different categories in the website like : Home, About Us, Gallery ( This will act as a Product Page with different sub categories ), Products, Contact Us
3. Users can upload their "Products" in our Galleries with the following limitations :

   - Users can upload their "Products" in our Gallery or Products or any Products related section. Not About Us, Contact Us.
   - Users will be able to upload only a fix number of "Products" depending on the membership fee they purchase from us
   - Users will not be able to set their "Product" prices, Admin will set it
4. Admin can also filter which "Product" to delete or approve
5. Uploaded "Product" will also be able to navigate from the Uploader's Profile
6. Any "Products" that is being sold, % amount of the sales will be credited into their account or any other payment method ( Kindly advise on this )

Not sure whether is it confusing. Hope you guys understand.

Thanks guys in advance.

Comment: Hi Yes its very much possible using marketplace and its addons https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Extensions/Marketplace.html

Comment: Thanks webkul! I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I do not exactly know the marketplace extension, but I think, it should be possible to change the template/controller logic of this module, to prevent that resellers can define a custom product price.

Perhaps you can ask the developers of marketplace if they would customize the extension to your needs. The support for payed magento extensions is very often better than expected.